# Could not create database SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Error When Creating a Database for Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I'm new in Symfony2 and I'm following the jobeet tutorials. I'm in day-2 and I'm trying to create a database using

```
php app/console doctrine:database:create
```

this command, and I'm getting

```
Could not create database for connection named `jobeet`
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'mergenc'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Here is my parameters.yml file

```
# This file is auto-generated during the composer install
parameters:
database_driver: pdo_mysql
database_host: localhost
database_port: 3306
database_name: jobeet
database_user: mergenc
database_password: 'password'
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
mailer_user: null
mailer_password: null
locale: en
secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
debug_toolbar: true
debug_redirects: false
use_assetic_controller: true
```

And here is my config.yml file

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
dbal:
    driver:   "%database_driver%"
    host:     "%database_host%"
    port:     "%database_port%"
    dbname:   "%database_name%"
    user:     "%database_user%"
    password: "%database_password%"
    charset:  UTF8
    # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver, add the path in parameters.yml
    # e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
    # path:     "%database_path%"

orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    auto_mapping: true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with :

```
database_driver: pdo_mysql
database_host: localhost
database_port: null
database_name: jobeet
database_user: mergenc
database_password: password
```

Answer (score 0):

did you have create the user 'mergenc' on your mysql server ? and he have administration right ?

are you sure your password is 'password' for mergenc

Comment: yes on my localhost in phpmyadmin I created a user called mergenc and gave it a password with all the privileges.